# Trouble connecting to my neighbors NAS

Tags: networking, nas, troubleshooting, dd-wrt, arp

I'm having trouble connecting to my neighbors NAS. We both live in the same student housing complex, and on the same hallway but for some reason i'm not able to connect using my rooms internet connection. Our routers are on the same subnet, use the same gateway and are both running on DD-WRT. The strange thing is that I am able to reach the NAS from my mobile connection (4G). I am a total noob with networks but i've tried the following to resolve the issue:

I did a trace route to my neighbors IP which came back with:

```
1  <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  DD-WRT [192.168.1.1]
2  ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ip.prioritytelecom.net [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]  
   reports: Destination host unreachable.
```

By googling i came to the conclusion that this means it can't get the MAC-address associated with the IP (correct me if i'm wrong), and that i could manually add it to the ARP table. So i asked my neighbor for his routers WAN MAC-address and added it to my routers ARP table. Now the host is no longer unreachable but instead i get a Request timed out.

```
1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  DD-WRT [192.168.1.1]
2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

After that i've tried  disabling the firewall on my neighbors router but that also didn't help. Does anyone know what the problem could be? Or how i could troubleshoot the problem?

Here's an image of what the infrastructure looks like:

[image: [infrastructure]

The xxx.xxx in the image is the same number for both routers

Comment: `I am able to reach the NAS from my mobile connection` So the NAS is exposed to the Internet? Did you use its internal or public IP to connect when you try to reach it via your router? Or did both failed?

Comment: Yes the NAS is exposed to the internet and i am trying to connect using using the public ip.

Comment: Then you should probably make your neighbour aware that their server is exposed and at risk.

Comment: Can your router ping the other router?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you read that you should add the MAC manually, but that is wrong. If adding the MAC manually helps, then there is something wrong with ARP resolution and should be fixed.

You question is missing many important details, such as the IP addresses of source (your computer), destination (NAS), both routers and their default gateway.

However, the fact that traceroute shows your own router as the first step indicates that source and target are not on the same network. However that may be because you try to access some dynamic DNS entry and not the NAS directly.

Based on the image you added, the routers have the same gateway, so the should be able to reach each other unless there is something in place to prevent it.

You should be able to reach you friend's router, and it should be possible to add a port forwarding from that router to the NAS, so it should be possible to reach the NAS. As you say you can already reach the NAS from your mobile connection, the port forwarding is already configured. So what is the target address are you using when connecting from the mobile connection and what is the target when connecting from inside your network?

Comment: I've added an image with the details of the infrastructure to the question

Comment: I added some paragraphs. Your router seems to have the address 192.168.1.1 on the inside. Does your friend's router have the same address or one from the same range?

Comment: looking at the image they are on different subnets, this could be the problem.

Comment: @Chris They are not. The problem could be that hey use the same range of private addresses on the inside.

Comment: xxx.xxx.167.x and xxx.xxx.166.x are those not different subnets?

Comment: @Chris, not necessarily... his subnet mask indicates a /23 notation. (510 usable hosts.) no one will be able to fully interpret this without both full ip addresses and subnet mask. unfortunately, it doesn't seem like he is comfortable giving that out, so no one will know where the subnet starts/ends or actual subnet number or broadcast address. all of the above are needed to fully interpret it.

Comment: @Chris The image states that the network is a /23, so xxx.xxx.167.x and xxx.xxx.166.x are definitely on the same subnet. Contrary to Tim_Stewart's post, an even number and the following odd number in the third octet always belong to the same /23 subnet.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I was not aware that you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the ISP denies switching between the hosts in the subnet (with the exception that when the default gateway is the destination), perhaps this can be solved by adding static route (to your router) for your neighbor's IP with the default gateway as gateway to "force routing".

P.S. Your neighbor's router would probably need similar route for your IP so that its replies can reach your router.